# Expected value of log-GARCH process

Tags: stochastic-processes, garch

Is there a way to analitycally compute expectation of log-GARCH process?

The GARCH(1,1) process:
$dU_t = \theta(\omega - U_t) dt +  \xi U_t d W_t$

The log-GARCH(1,1) process:
$e^{U_t}$

The expectation I'm interested in:
$m(t) = E[e^{U_t}]$

I can't find any explicit form (or any) of the GARCH process distribution, not to mention log-GARCH. Nethertheless, I have simulated $E[e^{U_t}]$ and it seems exponential, so I suspect, there migth be an explicit formula for $E[e^{U_t}]$. Is there?

Comment: Why is this a Garch process in the first place?

Comment: @Kiwiakos: I think, this is because $U_t$'s power is 1 (as it is in what's traditionally called GARCH(1,1)) in $\xi U_tdW_t$, as opposed to other models like square-root and $\frac{3}{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

To solve for $U_t$, we can proceed as follows. First, note that
\begin{align*}
d\left(e^{(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\xi^2)t - \xi W_t} U_t \right) &= e^{(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\xi^2)t - \xi W_t} U_t \left((\theta+\xi^2) dt -\xi dW_t\right) \\
&\qquad+ e^{(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\xi^2)t - \xi W_t} dU_t -\xi^2e^{(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\xi^2)t - \xi W_t} U_t dt\\
&=\theta \omega e^{(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\xi^2)t - \xi W_t} dt.
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
U_t &= U_0 e^{-(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\xi^2)t + \xi W_t } + \theta \omega \int_0^t e^{-(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\xi^2)(t-s) + \xi (W_t-W_s)} ds.
\end{align*}
From here, we can compute $E(U_t)$ analytically.

However, for Expectation $E(e^{U_t})$, we note the following. Let $\eta$ be a standard normal random variable. Then
\begin{align*}
E\left(e^{(e^{\eta})} \right) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{(e^x-1/2x^2)}dx \\
&=\infty,
\end{align*}
as 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}e^{(e^x-1/2x^2)} = \infty.
\end{align*}

Now, we consider $E\left(e^{U_t}\right)$. Note that, for $\theta \omega \geq 0$ and $U_0>0$,
\begin{align*}
U_t &= U_0 e^{-(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\xi^2)t + \xi W_t } + \theta \omega \int_0^t e^{-(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\xi^2)(t-s) + \xi (W_t-W_s)} ds\\
&\geq U_0 e^{-(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\xi^2)t + \xi W_t }.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
E(e^{U_t}) &\geq E\left(e^{U_0 e^{-(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\xi^2)t + \xi W_t }} \right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{U_0 e^{-(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\xi^2)t + \xi \sqrt{t} x-\frac{1}{2}x^2}}dx\\
&= \infty.
\end{align*}

NOTE: If $\omega =0$, then $U_t$ is log-normal. Related information: In the interest rate world, if the short rate $r_t$ is log-normal, then the money market account value $B_t = e^{\int_0^t r_s ds}$ has infinite expectation; see Page 63 of the book [Interest Rate Models](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540221492).

Comment: Thank for the answer!
Though I have a doubt concerning the first line: it seem that you have applied the differential product rule here - $d(uv) = udv + vdu$. But while in usual calculus $dvdu$ is infinitesimalvand doesn't count, in stochastics it yields additional term due to $dW_t dW_t = dt$.

Comment: Here it will be:
$$d e^{(\theta - \frac{1}{2}\xi^2)t - \xi W_t} dU_t = - \xi^2 U_t e^{(\theta - \frac{1}{2}\xi^2)t - \xi W_t} dt$$

So the second line will turn to be integral equation and i'm not sure the following analysis will still be relevant.

Comment: @Oleg: you are right. I will make the correction.

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks for your comments. I have made the correction by changing $\theta-\frac{1}{2}\xi^2$ to $\theta+\frac{1}{2}\xi^2$. The remaining analysis does not change.

Comment: Nice technique, thanks! 
But I'm still not sure that the $E(e^{e^\nu})$-argument proves that $E(e^{U_t})$ doesn't exist. Because, you know, $U_t$ has that integtal term apart from log-normal term.

Besides, I've made a simulation of $E(e^{U_t})$ and got some finite result for all $t$. Moreover, the whole problem comes from computing expected volatility of log-normal stochastic volatility in SV-model with GARCH-diffusion process for volatility. Namely, $E(e^{U_t})$ - is that expected volatility. Thus, I expect that expectation to exist, otherwise it would be a useless model.

Comment: Reference: Chernov et al. - 2003 - Alternative models for stock price dynamics.

Comment: @Oleg: More details are added.

Comment: You are right. The simulation for such thing as $E[e^{e^{W_t}}]$ is quite misleading, as the integral is infinite due to the contribution of events with super-low probability but with super-super-high weight, thus, most of the time the simulation will generate some finite result. It might be the reason, why a such model exists: while its theoretical expected volatility is infinite, it still can be calibrated and used as real indecies have bounded-support density functions (unlike normal distribution).

Comment: @Oleg: your interpretation is correct. That is why sometimes log-normal interest rate model, for example, the BDT model, is still being used.